# How to use Flags attribute?

Tags: c#, sql-server, enums, flags

I have some items in database. Each of'em can have many tags, like Browsable, or IsInMenu and so on. A friend of mine suggested to use enums with Flags attribute to create an extensible solution. So, I created a field in DB which takes an integer value, then I created this enum:

```
 [Flags]
 public enum ItemTags { Browsable = 2, IsInMenu = 4}
```

Now I'd like to be able to semantically get the list of some items this way:

```
 public List<Item> GetItems(ItemTags tags)
 {
     /* 
     Code to get data from DB, something like, 
     return repository.GetList(tags);
     */
 }
```

and in UI, I'd like to call:

```
 List<Item> items =  GetItems(ItemTags.Browsable | ItemTags.IsInMneu);
```

But I don't get the desired result. Am I going the right way?
By desired result, I mean this:
Values stored in database could be one of the 0, 2, 4, 6 values now. 0 means that the item is not in Menu and also not Browsable. 2 Means that item is Browable, but not in Menu. 4 means item is in Menu, but not Browsable. 6 means item is both Browsable and IsInMenu. Now when I call `GetItems` function, I don't get all the items which are browsable, in menu, or both browsable and in menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the **FlagsAttribute Class**

> Indicates that an enumeration can be
>   treated as a bit field; that is, a set
>   of flags.

```
[Flags] 
public enum ItemTags 
{ 
  Default =0,
  Browsable = 2, 
  IsInMenu = 4,
  All = 6 // Browsable / IsInMenu
}
```

[More here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

**note about enums:**

> an Enum by default has an int
>   under­neath, and as do all inte­gers
>   in C# an enum has a default value of 0
>   when first cre­ated. So if 0 is not
>   mapped to an enu­mer­a­tion con­stant
>   then your enum will be instan­ti­ated
>   with an invalid valid

Comment: This solution is fine. But what if my tags expand. I mean, in that case, I should write all the combinations, which is really hard. As I'd said in question, I want to be able to say `GetAllItems(ItemTags.IsInMenu | ItemTags.Browsable)`, not `GetAllItems(ItemTags.All)`. Am I right?

Comment: I think you would do a ItemTags.All, since the flagg attribute allows in this case no other enumvalue with a value 6 that represents something different than ItemTags.IsInMenu | ItemTags.Browsable, so both options are the same.

Comment: Surely these Flag values are incorrect and should be powers of 2?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `FlagsAttribute`, see this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), and this [usage example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum-flags), and most importantly this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the [`Flags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) attribute...

Your enum should be declared like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum ItemTags { Browsable = 2, IsInMenu = 4}
```

**EDIT:**
After your update, it looks fine. You should be more precise in what you mean with:

> But I don't get the desired result.

The code you showed us looks fine. So either there is a problem elsewhere or the code you really use in your application and the code you showed us here are different.